# how do i get PHP / REGEXP to match all keywords, instead of any?

Tags: php, mysql, regex, search

I have a PHP / mySQL search function that uses one or more keywords in the value $keywords_search . The problem is that it matches ANY keywords, meaning if a search is done it returns results that either contain just "milk" or just "beer" if someone searches for "milk beer". How do I change it so that the result must contain ALL keywords in the string?

The following is the code:

```
$query[] = "((a.name REGEXP '( )*(" . str_replace(' ', ')*( )*(', $keywords_search) . ")( )*') 
OR (a.description REGEXP '( )*(" . str_replace(' ', ')*( )*(', $keywords_search) . ")( )*'))";
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You'd be better off putting your keywords into a normalized child table, which makes such searches trivial. MySQL's regex matching doesn't allow you to specify how many of a series of alternations should be matched, it just tells you if ANY of them matched.

e.g

```
SELECT count(*) AS cnt
FROM keywords
WHERE keyword IN ('a', 'b', 'c')
GROUP BY id
HAVING (cnt = 3)
```

would bring up only those records where any particular id has all three keywords present.

With the regex version and an un-normalized string field, you'd have to split the keywords into multiple separate regexes and chain them with `AND`

e.g.

```
SELECT ...
FROM ...
WHERE keyword REGEX ('keyword1') AND keyword REGEX ('keyword2') AND ....
```

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. The script is a bit complex before and after with additional stuff that prevents me from using mySQL commands :(

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this with your keywords:

```
$keywords = array('key', 'word');

$keywordQuery = [];

foreach ($keywords as $keyword) {
    $keywordQuery[] = "((a.name REGEXP '( )*({$keyword})( )*') AND (a.description REGEXP '( )*({$keyword})( )*'))";
}

$query = implode(' AND ', $keywordQuery);
```

Better than Regexp, you could also use MySQL's fulltext searching if you can - [Boolean Full-Text Searches](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/fulltext-boolean.html).

Comment: Probably won't work if `$keywords_search` is something like `a|b|c`. It'd still match on even just one of the keywords.

Comment: Yeah, that's the problem. The script is a bit complex before and after with additional stuff that prevents me from using mySQL commands :(

Comment: Have you looked into using MySQL's fulltext searching instead?